# Efficient way to search in a NSDictionary of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSDictionary where each value is another NSDictionary with 3 keys:
@"URL", @"DATE" and @"META".

I need to efficiently retrieve the @"DATE" value of the dictionary with the @"URL" key equal to a particular NSURL.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand KVC: http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/

Example: 
https://gist.github.com/TonnyXu/3447781

**EDIT:**

As *Nick Lockwood* states: http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/high-performance-collection-looping-objective-c.html

> When enumerating an NSDictionary
>
> - Use [dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:] most of the time.
> - Use for (id key in [dictionary allKeys]) if you need to modify the dictionary.
> - Try [dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectWithOptions:usingBlock:] if your code might benefit from parallel execution.

Comment: KVC is easy and powerful, but I'm not sure it's the most CPU-efficient way to go. It's my understanding that it is fairly CPU expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSDictionary methods

```
enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:
```

or

```
keysOfEntriesPassingTest:
```

Knowing how to use blocks is very very valuable for any iOS programming.

Comment: Seems like `keysOfEntriesWithOptions:passingTest:` would be the best bet. You could request concurrent processing with the options, and if you only want 1 result you could make your block set stop=YES on the first match.

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSPredicate like as follows

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"URL == %@", aURL];
```

Then use the allValues method of NSDictionary to get an NSArray of values. After that apply the predicate to that NSArray.

```
NSArray * arrays =  [[dic allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```